# Store pid of a forked process in a file

Tags: linux, shell

I have the following but I'm worried about `$!` being overwritten prior to the echo command taking place. How do you guys recommend going about this?

```
sleep 100 & >/dev/null ; echo $! >sleep.pid
```

Comment: Why are you backgrounding a sleep command?

Comment: This is just an example here.

Comment: It will be difficult to answer such an abstract question.  I strongly advise you to be more concrete about what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to write the process id of a command I'm forking in a file while avoiding any possibility of concurrency.

Comment: What makes you think there's a possibility of `$!` being overwritten?

Comment: $! is the pid of the most recent background command stackoverflow.com/a/5163260/226255 .. What if, between the "firing" of sleep takes place and echo starts (I know it's probably just a millisecond) some other command gets forked?

Comment: After running a brief test, i've found that i can fork a process under one instance of bash, and it has no effect on the value of `$!` under other instances of bash. I'm quite certain that the value of `$!` in one session is the pid of the last backgrounded process in that particular session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash is designed such that it cannot happen as you've described it.  The value of `$!` in one session is the pid of the last backgrounded process **in that particular session**.

Comment: This works granted the first command does not fork any commands (check  discussion on stackoverflow about it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720131/store-the-forked-process-id-in-file). I'll accept this answer.

Comment: My console disagrees.